# Performance difference between is_a? / kind_of? vs class.name for class comparison in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to know which approach is more efficient in comparing two classes.

Approach 1:

```
a = '123'
a.class.name == 'String'
```

Approach 2:

```
a = '123'
a.kind_of? String
```

Any pointers would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would argue `is_a?` is the correct one. Not because of performance, but because of correctness.

It is perfectly fine to have multiple `String` classes in your app, therefore it is not enough to just compare the class name. `.class.name == 'String'` only returns if the name of the class is “String”, but it doesn't tell if it is the same `String` class that would be returned when you called `String` in the current context.

Whereas `kind_of?` does not only check if `a` is an instance of `String`. It would also return `true` if `a` is an instance of a subclass of `String`.

You asked about what approach is most *efficient*, but did not tell how you define *efficient* in the context of your question. `is_a?` is the shortest, I would argue that is *efficient*. When you were thinking about performance, let's have a look at this:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

string = "123"

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("name == name") { string.class.name == "String" }
  x.report("kind_of?") { string.kind_of?(String) }
  x.report("is_a?") { string.is_a?(String) }
end

Warming up --------------------------------------
    name == name   585.361k i/100ms
        kind_of?     1.173M i/100ms
           is_a?     1.299M i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
    name == name      5.870M (± 4.6%) i/s -     29.853M in   5.099899s
        kind_of?     12.803M (± 3.0%) i/s -     64.514M in   5.043457s
           is_a?     12.971M (± 3.6%) i/s -     64.935M in   5.012808s
```

Turns out, `is_a?` is also the fastest.

Comment: `kind_of?` also checks included modules, e.g. `'foo'.kind_of?(Comparable) #=> true`